Combine different tables and each table has subtable in excel using Pandas
I have a table for everyday. In each table, there are some sub-table. I copy a table from one day here. the top row is the header, the second row is the department name, then the rest of rows are the real table. There are 3 departments, C1, H1, C2. In each table, the row number is different for each department. There are some blank rows before the header and each department. Meanwhile, in two adjacent columns, some cell are merged two cells but some cells are not.
PtSex   AccessionNumber PtOrderLoc  BatTstCode  TestCode    ResultTech  Result

C1                      
M   T527551 SV8S    LACT    LACT    63538   7.3
F   W523244 SV10S   BMETPL  K   64020   3.0
F   W523527 SV9S    BMETPL  K   64020   2.9
F   W524065 SV9N    LACT    LACT    63538   2.2
M   W524581 SVED    LACT    LACT    63538   4.5
M   W525161 SVED    LACT    LACT    63538   4.4
M   W525541 SV8S    LACT    LACT    63538   6.2
M   W525814 SV7S    BMETPL  K   64020   3.0
M   W525909 SVED    LACT    LACT    64020   3.2
M   W528201 SV6N    LACT    LACT    64020   4.9
M   W528327 SVED    BMETPL  GLUC    64020   655
M   W528430 SVED    LACT    LACT    64020   2.4
F   W530400 INF CMPMTP  K   63443   2.5
M   W531251 SV8S    LACT    LACT    64020   3.9
M   W531604 SV7S    K   K   64020   3.0
F   W531785 SVED    LACT    LACT    64158   2.3
M   W533213 SV6N    LACT    LACT    64158   3.0
M   W533765 SVED    LACT    LACT    64158   2.2
M   W533788 SV8S    LACT    LACT    86545   2.7
F   W534079 SVED    CMPMTP  CO2 64158   >40
F   W534549 SVED    BMETPL  K   64158   2.5
F   W535413 SVED    LACT    LACT    64158   2.7
M   W535851 SV8S    LACT    LACT    64158   2.3
                        
H1                      
F   T522281 SVED    CBCAD   HCT 5003    21.0
F   T522281 SVED    CBCAD   HGB 5003    6.1
F   T522281 SVED    CBCAD   PLT 5003    20
F   W522938 SV9S    CBCAD   WBC 5004    1.7
F   W523833 SV9S    CBC HGB 5003    6.3
F   W523833 SV9S    CBC PLT 5003    25
M   W524366 SV10S   CBC HGB 5004    6.7
M   W525538 SV8S    CBCAD   HCT 5003    16.7
M   W525538 SV8S    CBCAD   HGB 5003    5.9
F   W526103 SV10S   CBCAD   HGB 5003    6.9
F   W528442 SV10S   CBC HGB 5003    7.0
F   W532511 SV9S    CBC PLT 5003    23
M   W533852 SVED    CBCAD   HCT 5003    19.0
M   W533852 SVED    CBCAD   HGB 5003    6.5
F   W534077 SV8E    CBC HGB 5003    6.9
F   W534693 SVED    CBCAD   WBC 5003    1.9

C2                      
F   T525997 SV9N    PTT PTTAVE  64158   108

Can anyone help me combine them together and separate by department using pandas?
Thanks,

I would suggest fixing your data first. Instead of a 'sub table' why not add another column with department name? that way it would be easier to manipulate the data how you are describing

I got the data from IT and that is what I get.

thats fine, what is your expected output then?

I saved the data you provided as a csv file and created a dataframe from it.
IIUC, you want to combine each sub table into a singular dataframe.
you can do this:
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=" ", skipinitialspace=True)

df["Department"] = df["PtSex"][df["AccessionNumber"].isna()]
df["Department"] = df["Department"].ffill()
df = df.dropna().set_index('Department')
print(df.to_string())

Results:
             PtSex AccessionNumber PtOrderLoc BatTstCode TestCode  ResultTech Result
Department
C1             M         T527551       SV8S       LACT     LACT     63538.0    7.3
C1             F         W523244      SV10S     BMETPL        K     64020.0    3.0
C1             F         W523527       SV9S     BMETPL        K     64020.0    2.9
C1             F         W524065       SV9N       LACT     LACT     63538.0    2.2
C1             M         W524581       SVED       LACT     LACT     63538.0    4.5
C1             M         W525161       SVED       LACT     LACT     63538.0    4.4
C1             M         W525541       SV8S       LACT     LACT     63538.0    6.2
C1             M         W525814       SV7S     BMETPL        K     64020.0    3.0
C1             M         W525909       SVED       LACT     LACT     64020.0    3.2
C1             M         W528201       SV6N       LACT     LACT     64020.0    4.9
C1             M         W528327       SVED     BMETPL     GLUC     64020.0    655
C1             M         W528430       SVED       LACT     LACT     64020.0    2.4
C1             F         W530400        INF     CMPMTP        K     63443.0    2.5
C1             M         W531251       SV8S       LACT     LACT     64020.0    3.9
C1             M         W531604       SV7S          K        K     64020.0    3.0
C1             F         W531785       SVED       LACT     LACT     64158.0    2.3
C1             M         W533213       SV6N       LACT     LACT     64158.0    3.0
C1             M         W533765       SVED       LACT     LACT     64158.0    2.2
C1             M         W533788       SV8S       LACT     LACT     86545.0    2.7
C1             F         W534079       SVED     CMPMTP      CO2     64158.0    >40
C1             F         W534549       SVED     BMETPL        K     64158.0    2.5
C1             F         W535413       SVED       LACT     LACT     64158.0    2.7
C1             M         W535851       SV8S       LACT     LACT     64158.0    2.3
H1             F         T522281       SVED      CBCAD      HCT      5003.0   21.0
H1             F         T522281       SVED      CBCAD      HGB      5003.0    6.1
H1             F         T522281       SVED      CBCAD      PLT      5003.0     20
H1             F         W522938       SV9S      CBCAD      WBC      5004.0    1.7
H1             F         W523833       SV9S        CBC      HGB      5003.0    6.3
H1             F         W523833       SV9S        CBC      PLT      5003.0     25
H1             M         W524366      SV10S        CBC      HGB      5004.0    6.7
H1             M         W525538       SV8S      CBCAD      HCT      5003.0   16.7
H1             M         W525538       SV8S      CBCAD      HGB      5003.0    5.9
H1             F         W526103      SV10S      CBCAD      HGB      5003.0    6.9
H1             F         W528442      SV10S        CBC      HGB      5003.0    7.0
H1             F         W532511       SV9S        CBC      PLT      5003.0     23
H1             M         W533852       SVED      CBCAD      HCT      5003.0   19.0
H1             M         W533852       SVED      CBCAD      HGB      5003.0    6.5
H1             F         W534077       SV8E        CBC      HGB      5003.0    6.9
H1             F         W534693       SVED      CBCAD      WBC      5003.0    1.9
C2             F         T525997       SV9N        PTT   PTTAVE     64158.0    108

